# Отправка ответа на POST запрос из файла js

Tags: javascript, php

Из js файла отправляется запрос на файл php, который хранится на веб-сервере.
Знаю, как выдать ответ, если форма отправляется из html страницы, но как выдать ответ на запрос из файла?
Запрос отправляется в виде: `await fetch(ip, {method:"POST", body: "test"})`

Comment: [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Простите, дал недостаточно инфы. Этот js-файл находится на другом веб-сервере

Comment: CORS заголовки выставьте в пхп, если ответ не принимается в файле обратно.

Comment: Спасибо, я во всем разобрался с помощью postman. Я неправилно отправлял запрос